# Will 2 divorces from the first marriage still count in a new marriage with the same woman?

Tags: nikah, talaq, iddah

In a case where a man has issued 2 divorces with the same woman in the first marriage and then they got together in a new relationship 1 year later, will the 2 divorces from the previous marriage still count in the new marraige even though if you had made a new proposal and marriage contract?

Comment: @Medi1Saif You have previously answered one of my question with great quality. Could you provide an answer regarding this question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first two divorces will count. That means if a husband divorces his wife one more time, the reconciliation cannot be made unless she marries someone else and then he can marry her again.

Comment: I can't find any sources confirming this specific case, not that I'm saying your answer is wrong, but I find this question a little bit complex.

Comment: I answered this based on common sense. May be someone can provide more authentic answer.